# How to post and get value number? when use modal bootstrap in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, get, bootstrap-modal

I used to get page number value from Contents.ejs to Contents_detail.ejs

But I'm going to use Modal bootstrap.

So I need get number value from contents page to contents page

Want a page read view count +1

```html
<!--- contents.ejs ---->

<!--- contents list --->
<% for(var i=0; i<contents.length; i++) { %>
  <li>
    <div align="center">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= contents[i].con_photo %>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#coupon-modal<%=contents[i].con_no%>" data-backdrop="static">
    </div>

    <div class="con row">
      <p>
        <a href="#">
          <%=contents[i].con_title %>
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <% } %>

    <!-- modal contents detail page --->
    <% for(var i=0; i<contents.length; i++) { %>
      <div id="coupon-modal<%=contents[i].con_no%>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" align="center" style="">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

              <div class="contents container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 title">
                    <%=contents[i].con_viewCount%>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <% } %>
```

```js
router.get('/contents', function(req, res, next) {
  var row;
  mysql.select('select c.con_no, c.con_category, c.con_writer, c.con_title, c.con_content, c.con_photo, c.con_viewCount,c.con_regDate, c.con_upDate, c.con_likeCnt, c.comment_no, c.user_no, c.user_comment, c.con_release,  u.user_email, u.user_name, u.user_profile_img, u.user_sns_url, u.user_sns_icon, cate.cate_no, cate.cate_name from cider.cid_contents c left join cider.cid_user u on u.user_no = c.user_no left join cider.cid_con_cate cate on c.con_category = cate.cate_no and u.user_level = "2" where 1=1 limit 0,30', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    row = data;

    mysql.update('update cider.cid_contents set con_viewCount = con_viewCount + 1 where con_no = ?', [no], function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.redirect('back');
      }

      res.render('front/cid_contents/cid_contents_popular', {
        contents: row
      });
    });
  });
});
```